# Wpf alignment button

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

I think I can create shred size of grid but I'm not sure. Could you help me please. How can I do it? 
[image]

Comment: not sure if I understand your requirement

Comment: Any reason, the `HorizontalAlignment` property of the button cannot be used?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ, good idea if goal is to simply center something.

Comment: @Sinatr yes, the question is well answered by our question .. good job :) +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize `Grid` columns to automatically center your content (`a` is unknown) like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- content in the middle -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="1"> ... </Grid>
</Grid>
```

If your intents are to ensure what `a` is the *minimum necessary width* (left and right content should have same width), then it's opposite:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="a" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="a" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- left content -->
    <Grid> ... </Grid>
    <!-- right content -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="2"> ... </Grid>
</Grid>
```